# Does the CLR create Type object on the heap right before each method invocation or does it just use already created Type object?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

My question is does the CLR create Type object on the heap right before each method invocation or does it just use already created Type object?
For instance, let's say we have Person class and two methods which uses this Person type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As we know CLR scans method body before execution to create Type object for the types which are used by this method. So, how many Person type object will be created in that case? Will CLR create two type object or will it use already created Type object?

Comment: The JIT doesn't need a `Type` object - it just needs to *resolve the type* to the type's handle / metadata - I wouldn't expect it to be using the *managed* API, though...

Comment: Unless you use some dirty tricks, there is only one `Type` object per type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your final question :

> Will CLR create two type object or will it use already created Type
>   object?

**It will use already created one**

Here it goes, taken directly from Jeffery Ritcher CLR via C# epic book :

> Just before the Main method executes, the CLR detects all of the types
>   that are referenced by Main’s code. This causes the CLR to allocate an
>   internal data structure that is used to manage access to the
>   referenced types. In Figure 1-4, the Main method refers to a single
>   type, Console, causing the CLR to allocate a single internal
>   structure. This internal data structure contains an entry for each
>   method defined by the Console type. Each entry holds the address where
>   the method’s implementation can be found. When initializing this
>   structure, the CLR sets each entry to an internal, undocumented
>   function contained inside the CLR itself. I call this function
>   JITCompiler.

[image]

So this eventually means that runtime will create Type first time it sees before executing executing method and if that that Type is present in different assembly, it will try loading that assembly first (of course using assembly reference metadata in assembly manifest file)